# Find steps in list that have value that doesn't change in some interval using python

Tags: python, arrays

I have two lists of values. One is list :

```
x={0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9,2.0}
```

and corresponding y value is given with another list:

```
y={0.0001,0.005,0.01,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.23,0.24,0.25,0.26,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.7,0.8}
```

Is there a way that I can use Python to find all steps that occur in y list that doesn't change as x corresponding values are changed, i.e. get as result values of steps 0.2,0.3, and corresponding interval of x values for value of y=0.2, and y=0.3?

Comment: These are sets, not lists !

Comment: Consider those x and y as arrays of given numbers.

Comment: @Theorist I edited it. Note, lists are not the same as arrays either!

Comment: Please define what you mean by "steps". Could that be all the possible pairs of values in y (or in x) ?  Also clarify the relationship you want between the two lists. Is it positional or based on the first/last occurrence of matching values ?

Comment: @Neil how can you edit the code? You seem to know that he has lists, and the code is wrong. Why isn't that he has sets, and the terminology in the question is wrong? I'm more inclined to believe that this is a copy-paste of the actual code, and the terminology in the question is imprecise.

Comment: Well the python syntax says those are sets, we cannot consider them as arrays, please fix your code accordingly

Comment: @Gsk OP asked about lists. The question can't be "wrong". If they meant sets then they must open a new question.

Comment: I think you need reputation to edit a question

Comment: @Neil The [Editing code guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code) states: "_Code in questions should only be edited for formatting and readability. Editing the syntax or correcting typos in code in questions can fix the problem that the person asking the question has, causing answers to be unable to address the problem._"

Comment: I am reading values from a .dat file that consists of two columns of some data, and I store those values as x and y, that I can later plot if I want, but at the moment I am just analyzing them as I have specified. I get x and y with x,y=loadtxt('data.dat',unpack=True). Type of x and y in python is numpy.ndarray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for the indexes i such as y_i == y_{i - 1}, you can try this:

```
res = []
tmp = -1
for i, yi in enumerate(y):
    if yi == tmp:
        res.append(i)

    tmp = yi
```

This gives [4, 5, 6, 7, 13, 14, 15]

Comment: Thanks, I think this will be helpful.